# Way to set up a list, where depending on permission, admin will see all

Tags: list-view, groups, sharepoint-views, sharepoint-permissions

I'm trying to setup a list where an "Admin" can see all entries but a user can only see their own?
I found this YouTube video by SharePointQuester and all he is using are web parts with different views and setting the permissions on the views ([https://youtu.be/exVN5S89KTc](http://SharePointQuester)).

It seems like what I am looking for.  One of the List views (the Users) will have the filter set to [ME].  Then there is another view for the Admin with no filter.

So I guess my question is, I can just base permissions and what folks see by the way I filter views, then put them in a group that controls the access to the views?  There is nothing non-OOTB solution needed for this (don't need to make it a 'code' solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is one way of doing what you are looking for.

But OOB, lists have the ability to automatically filter the list so that ‘regular’ users can only View and Edit the items they created - this is applied to All users unless they have the ‘Cancel Check Out Permissions’ (i.e.: what you term ‘Admin’ users) *See yellow portion of the attached image.*

You can regulate what the ‘regular’ users see in the sections circled in green and red in the attached image.

The benefit of using this over applying permissions on different views is that you only have to manage permissions for two groups, not permissions AND views as per your question.

```
Please mark this as answer if it helped you
```

get to this setting by going to list options —> Advanced Settings
[image]

Comment: @a-k-a-fritz, thanks, this did answer my question.  I'll have to tweak because now the customer wants it so that instead of the individual seeing their own, everyone in the individual's group can see their group entries.  I'll mark it as an answer.  Thanks!